# How to fix "Error: The server does not support SSL connections" when trying to access database in localhost?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am following Heroku's [node.js tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database) to provision a Postgres database. 
After creating a simple table and connecting to localhost:5000/db, I get an error saying "Error: The server does not support SSL connections".

I've been searching for solutions for hours but can't seem to fix it. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you set `ssl = on` in `postgresql.conf`, provide server certificates and restart the server?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here I provide a workaround for the question, and not the title of this post. A better answer to the post overall would probably address configuring SSL for the local machine.

I arrived here trying to resolve the problem of finishing that Heroku tutorial mentioned in the question and setting up the Postgres database to work locally as well as remotely.

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgresql://postgres:<your admin password>@localhost:5432/<your db name>',
    ssl: process.env.DATABASE_URL ? true : false
})
```

My idea is to use SSL on the app I deploy but dodge SSL altogether on the local machine. By simply skipping SSL config on the local machine I am able to concentrate my efforts on developing a working app that still uses Heroku's built in SSL.

I use the Heroku environment variables to detect their environment versus my own and I select values accordingly in the code sample above. For me this has worked both locally and remotely.

Comment: Im new to strapi but I think nowadays we use `config/env/production` for prod config files, and local config files can be under `config/`

Answer (score 11):

This is the new form Heroku is working today in 2021, they made small corrections in the connection.

```
const pool = (() => {
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    return new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: false
    });
} else {
    return new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
          }
    });
} })();
```

They changed a bit, using this way you can keep local and heroku available.

Answer (score 7):

This helped me, when I was using connectionUrl.

```
postgres://password:postgres@localhost:5432/database?sslmode=disable
```

> You might have noticed I have added `?sslmode=disable` at the end of
> connection url.

For more information about `sslmode` check [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html) out.

Answer (score 4):

Best solution that I found that worked only:

```
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: productiondbLink || localdblink,
    ssl: process.env.DATABASE_URL ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : false
});

client.connect();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for setting up my local environment after the tutorial. Sticking to the command `heroku local` to start my server fixed it for me. This command is detailed in the [Run the app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally) section of the tutorial.

In my case I added a Express server and a client side using React + Webpack. My `package.json` scripts for local development look like:

```json
"dev": "run-p dev:*",
"dev:server": "heroku local -f Procfile.dev",
"dev:webpack": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js --mode development",
```

- `run-p` is just from `npm-run-all` to run all scripts starting with `dev` at the same time.
- The server uses the `heroku local` command and a specific `Procfile` for local development (use `-f` flag to do this), where I start a server locally with `nodemon` to watch for changes (see the `Procfile.dev` below).
- The webpack script builds and watches for changes on the client side with React.

`Procfile.dev` for local development:

```
web: nodemon index.js
```

`Procfile` for production:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 index.js
```

Then the same code for connecting to the DB from the [Provision a database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database) section works for me:

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, also check that the `connectionString` that your are passing to the Pool instance is correct (and not undefined), this would trigger the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I came here not looking for a localhost solution (I wanted to connect to my db which is online), however, this turned up as the first google result, so I'll add a solution for **not localhost** issues here:

Check out the .env file to duplicate the Environment variables you setup in your heroku environment; see here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

const pool = new Pool({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5432/',
ssl: process.env.DATABASE_URL ? true : false
})

In your code, you add this snippet with the credentials and connection string details, here process.env.DATABASE_URL comes from environment file, if it is there as it will enable ssl mode, else in local without ssl it works. Make sure, you will mention env variable only for other than local. So on both environment it works.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I had to edit the `database.js` file.
Path to file:

`<path-to-your-strapi-project>/config/database.js`

if you find something with `ssl` that is set to `true` set it to `false`. In my case, I used `Mysql` it looked like this:

`ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', true)`

**Change it to:**

`ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false)`