# Error: The server does not support SSL connections | PostgreSQL + Knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I have my back-end at Heroku. The connection file looks like this:

```
const knex = require("knex")({
  client: "pg",
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    port: 5432,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
});
```

The listening:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

At insomnia:

[Insomnia route + body + error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1EZX.png)

I'm able to test my application through the Heroku deploy without problems, but locally, i cannot. My env variables are configured, everything works fine, except the localhost requests.

Any ideias?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302088/how-to-fix-error-the-server-does-not-support-ssl-connections-when-trying-to-a

Comment: I couldn't find an answer there since they're using pool instead of knex :/

Comment: [Configure the server to support SSL connections.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the problem guys. My dotenv wasn't working properly. Although my files were in the correct place, exactly how the documentation asks for, my .env wasn't being recognized (?). I found out this by console logging one of my environment variables. Found out to be undefined, so I pointed out the location of the .env file (default location, above src folder...), and everything started working as it should.